# How do I remove an empty element in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of email address, but an empty string gets injected into the end of the array. How can I remove this element in the array?

```
for(int i = 0; i < allToAddresses.Length; i++)
{
    if(allToAddresses[i] == " ") // find where empty element is
    { //Here i am trying to delete that empty element. does not work
       allToAddresses[i].Split("".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you consistently get a final entry with an empty string, you should also try to find the cause, rather than fix the array.  That's assuming it's your code, or code you have some control over (team member's).

Answer (score 7):

You could try to use Linq for this

```
allToAddresses = allToAddresses.Where(address=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address))
                               .ToArray();
```

You have to include also this in your namespaces:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You filter your initial array using the `Where` method. In this method you pass a predicate that returns true if for the current address the method string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace returns false. Otherwise it returns false. Using this filter you discard the addresses that are null, empty, or consisted only of white-space characters.

Comment: `.Where(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace)` would not compile

Comment: @haim my bad :( Thanks for spotting my typo

Comment: `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` also does not compile.  Error is: "CS0023 Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'"

Answer (score 4):

```
test =  test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhitepace(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: He probably needs `string.IsNullOrWhitepace(x)` because his question includes `" "` which isn't empty, it's whitespace.

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(" ");` doesn't work since it has whitespace.

Comment: Yeah sorry i over looked that, yes in that case it must be a NullOrWhitespace. I will edit the answer. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot truly "remove" elements from an array, because array size is fixed<sup>*</sup>. You can, however, construct a new array that skips all empty elements:

```
allToAddresses = allToAddresses.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```

The above requires using `System.Linq` at the top of your file. It checks all entries in your array to see if they are null or consist entirely of white space (spaces, tabs, etc.) and produces a new array of strings, containing only non-empty / non-null entries from the original array.

<sup>*</sup> In the interest of full disclosure, .NET does have [an API that lets you modify array size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx), but you should not use it in situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using arrays, you will need to pull the valid values out and put them into a new instance of an array. You can do something like this:

```
internal static T[] RemoveNullArrayElements<T>(T[] array)
    {
        if (array != null)
        {
            List<T> newLst = new List<T>();
            foreach (var ar in array)
            {
                if (ar != null)
                {
                    newLst.Add(ar);
                }
            }
            return newLst.ToArray();
        }

        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be that you are searching for white space instead of an empty string?

Try below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < allToAddresses.Length; i++)
{
   if(allToAddresses[i] == "") // find where empty element is
   { //Here i am trying to delete that empty element. does not work
      allToAddresses[i].Split("".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   }
}
```